# Why are comparisons the dominant cost in any reasonable implementation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time, complexity-theory

I am reading a textbook on algorithms. The textbook says that the comparison operation is the dominant cost in any reasonable implementation. Why is this? What makes it so slow?

Comment: Do you mean in the context of sorting?

Comment: I read this sentence in the context of quick-sort, but I believe the author is implying it's more general than that.

Comment: I'd say in most machines, array swap is more costly than comparison. The point is that comparison is used much more times compared to other operations. The other operation used just as many times as comparison is the increment, which is less costly.

Comment: Is there anything specific to the comparison operation that makes it slower? Is it the fact you need to compare every bit between the two numbers?

Comment: @Mephy -- your sentence seems to imply array swap could be the dominant cost, since in the worst-case, it appears that the number of array swaps is equal to number of comparisons.

Comment: In my view, it could be the dominant cost in the worst-case scenario, but I'm not entirely sure what the author meant in the context (thus why I just commented it).

Comment: Could you possibly explain why array swap is slower than comparison?

Comment: It's not so much that the comparison operation is the dominant cost - comparisons are often among the faster instructions - but that the comparisons are often the controlling influence over loops, dictating how many times other operations are performed. Thus you often count computational complexity by counting comparisons.

Comment: @twalberg Your explanation makes sense. However, the textbook explicitly uses the word "cost". I'll ask my professor, for a greater discussion about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are used to textbook examples, like sorting arrays of integers or so, where comparisons are cheap.  Well, welcome to the real world, things are a bit more complicated here.  In many cases a comparison operation is more than just one "`if`", it's typically a rather complicated callback function.   It starts with calculating the actual key to be compared as a function of the object.  A simple example would be comparing strings case-independently.  Here you first have to normalize the case of each string.  Then you have to compare the strings character by character.  This is a lot of work, much more work than, say, swapping two `char*`.  Or think of comparing trees:  Within one comparison operation you may have to follow many branches of both trees.

And even if you have a data structure where the comparison itself is very simple, it's always followed by a conditional jump.  Conditional jumps are expensive, they take around 15..25 clock cycles in modern processors, assuming the hardware cannot easily predict the result.  That's a very long time, typically the CPU can do one operation within one clock cycle.